# dpkg-genbuildinfo: error: badly formed line in files list file, line 1

Tags: packaging, deb

I am trying to debianize a collection of shell scripts. The build itself is quite simple, as there are no binaries to build – every file that will be installed on the target system is already present in the source tree.

Now the build process fails with an error message I cannot make sense of:

```
dpkg-genbuildinfo: error: badly formed line in files list file, line 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genbuildinfo subprocess returned exit status 25
debuild: fatal error at line 1182:
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui failed
```

What is the files list file mentioned in the error message – does that refer to the `.install` file? The file looks like this:

```
src/main/shell/autorecover      opt/autorecover
src/main/shell/autorecover.d/lib/*      opt/autorecover.d/lib/
src/main/shell/autorecover.d/mods-available/*      opt/autorecover.d/mods-available/
```

The `debian` dir is copied and stripped down from another (more complex) package I built earlier, which completed without such errors iirc.

Nonetheless, I do end up with a deb package which seems to have everything in place – scripts as well as files to install. (Which indicates that the `.install` file cannot have been all that wrong, at least the files are getting collected.)

What is wrong here? What do I need to fix, or where should I start looking for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As further research showed, the “files list file” is an auto-generated file named `debian/files`. As I suspected, there was no issue with the `.install` file.

Looking at `debian/files`, the first line read

```
autorecover_0.0.1_all.deb net # FIXME optional
```

This line should have the form

```
name_version_arch.deb section optional
```

The section is taken from the `debian/control`. Here I had indeed added `# FIXME` after the section name as I wasn’t sure what to use.

Found the correct section (`admin` sounds like a good choice) and fixed the value, and the package builds.